# Camera preview layout is correct only after short delay

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom camera Activity that uses custom CameraPreview ViewGroup implementation. On pre 3.0 android everything works fine, but starting from 3.0 camera preview looks like in Picture 1. If I add Thread.sleep or do some debugging and delay onLayout method for a little bit then layout gets displayed as expected (Picture 2). I'm a bit at a loss here...

CameraPreview class:

```
public class CameraPreview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private final String TAG = "CameraPreview";

    private boolean mPreviewRunning = false;

    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Size mPreviewSize;
    private List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public boolean IsPreviewRunning() {
        return mPreviewRunning;
    }

    public CameraPreview(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public CameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        addView(mSurfaceView);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        mCamera = camera;
        if (mCamera != null) {            
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    public void switchCamera(Camera camera) {
       setCamera(camera);
       try {
           camera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
       } catch (IOException exception) {
           Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
       }
       Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
       parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
       requestLayout();

       camera.setParameters(parameters);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // We purposely disregard child measurements because act as a wrapper to a SurfaceView that 
        // centers the camera preview instead of stretching it.
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes == null && mCamera != null) {
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        }
        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);            
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        if (changed && getChildCount() > 0) {
            final View child = getChildAt(0);

            final int width = r - l;
            final int height = b - t;

            int previewWidth = width;
            int previewHeight = height;
            if (mPreviewSize != null) {
                previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
            }
            if (previewWidth == 0) {
                previewWidth = 1;
            }
            if (previewHeight == 0) {
                previewHeight = 1;
            }

            // Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
            if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth) {
                final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
                child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0, (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
            } else {
                final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
                child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2, width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where to draw.
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                mSupportedPreviewSizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        stop();
    }

    private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin the preview.
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            if (mPreviewSize != null) {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            }
            requestLayout();

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mPreviewRunning = true;
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mPreviewRunning = false;
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The layout where this class is used:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  >
  <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="2"
  android:padding="5dip"  
  >
      <com.commonlib.controls.CameraPreview
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:id="@+id/surface_camera"
      />
      <ImageView android:id="@+id/target"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/target"
        >
        </ImageView>
  </FrameLayout>
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:paddingLeft="7dip"
  android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="50dip"
      android:layout_height="0dip"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:id="@+id/cancel"
      android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert">
      </ImageButton>
    <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="50dip"
      android:layout_height="0dip"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:id="@+id/ok"
      android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera">
      </ImageButton>      
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

**UPDATE**
I found out that it only happens if calling Activity was in portrait mode.

**UPDATE 2**
It looks like this behavior is caused by screen rotation animation. Camera activity uses landscape mode. If calling activity is in a portrait mode - it causes screen rotation animation and this somehow messes camera preview control layout. I'm looking into how to disable screen rotation animation for this case or how to re-layout camera activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as suspected, all this was caused by rotation animation. During the rotation onMeasure width and height measurements exchanged their places (because of going from portrait to landscape) and thus the smallest margin was always taken into account. I solved it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // We purposely disregard child measurements because act as a wrapper to a SurfaceView that 
    // centers the camera preview instead of stretching it.
    int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

    // we only allow landscape, if height > width - it means that we are in rotation animation. Swap width with height
    if (height > width) {
        width += height;
        height = width - height;
        width = width - height;         
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    Log.v("Camera", width + "x" + height);

    if (mSupportedPreviewSizes == null && mCamera != null) {
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    }
    if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
        mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);            
    }
}
```